# Downloading the oldest available version of some data files

Tags: performance, http, matlab, curl

I am using the [cURL](http://curl.haxx.se/) tool in MATLAB 2013b with Ubuntu to download a whole bunch of files. The files have one of three possible versions: 1.0.0, 2.0.0, or 2.1.0. Using the HTTP, I first check the headers with three queries to see which version exists. Then whichever exists I download it. If none exists (because of nonexistent dates) then I just move on.

Is there any other more efficient way of querying and then downloading the files? For example, check 1.0.0. If it exists, download it. If it doesn't exist then check 2.0.0 and so on. The only way I can think of doing that was some very ugly nested if-elseif statements. But this way, I query three times no matter what so a little wasteful I think.

Also any other comments on my coding style are welcome.

```
    clc
    close all
    clear all

    for y = 2012:2013
    for m = 1:12
    for d = 1:31

    % To limit the dates because of the available data
    if y==2012 && m < 9
        continue
    elseif y==2013 && m > 9
        break
    end

    % The date string is created with padded zeros
    if (m < 10) && (d < 10)
        thedate = [num2str(y) '0' num2str(m) '0' num2str(d)];
    elseif m < 10
        thedate = [num2str(y) '0' num2str(m) num2str(d)];
    elseif d < 10
        thedate = [num2str(y) num2str(m) '0' num2str(d)];
    else
        thedate = [num2str(y) num2str(m) num2str(d)];
    end

    newname = ['ephemA' thedate '.h5']

    % The entire file name is created
    thefile = ['http://www.rbsp-ect.lanl.gov/data_pub/rbspa/MagEphem/def/rbspa_def_MagEphem_TS04D_' thedate];

    % Use curl with --head flag to check the header to see which version exists
    [status, result1] = system(['curl --head ' thefile '_v1.0.0.h5']);
    [status, result2] = system(['curl --head ' thefile '_v2.0.0.h5']);
    [status, result3] = system(['curl --head ' thefile '_v2.1.0.h5']);

    % 200 means the file exists and is downloaded
    if ~isempty(strfind(result1,'HTTP/1.1 200'))
        [status, result] = system(['curl -o ' newname ' ' thefile '_v1.0.0.h5']);
    elseif ~isempty(strfind(result2,'HTTP/1.1 200'))
        [status, result] = system(['curl -o ' newname ' ' thefile '_v2.0.0.h5']);
    elseif ~isempty(strfind(result3,'HTTP/1.1 200'))
        [status, result] = system(['curl -o ' newname ' ' thefile '_v2.1.0.h5']);
    end

    end
    end
    end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you read the index from http://www.rbsp-ect.lanl.gov/data_pub/rbspa/MagEphem/def/ and use that to decide which files you want to download?

Also, try to give multiple files (eg. 20) to each `curl` call: this will enable curl to [reuse the same connection for those files](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#What_about_Keep_Alive_or_persist).

Please also note that Matlab is not the right tool for this job. For example, this would be easier in Python which has many libraries to perform HTTP requests.

Comment: I am doing this in MATLAB because I do much more to the file when I download it. So instead of simply saving it, I download the file, process it, keep the data I want, and then delete it.